# here i am on my node js server 127.0.0.1/8081 and if click button then i want to switch server 127.0.0.1/8000

Tags: node.js, laravel-5

here I am on my node js server 127.0.0.1/8081 and if click button then I want to switch laravel server 127.0.0.1/8000

```
if (results.length==0){
    return res.redirect('/alert.html');
}
else{
    return res.redirect('/acess');//from here i want switch server to 127.0.0.1/8000
}
```

Comment: What have you tried. Sorry but StackOverflow is about helping people fix their existing programming code. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two different servers, `127.0.0.1:8000` and `127.0.0.1:8081`.

You are running your nodeJS code on 127.0.0.1:8000 and when you need to redirect to `127.0.0.1:8081`, you need to provide full URL instead relative URL.

use `res.redirect('http://127.0.0.1:8000/acess')`

Your code will become

```
if (results.length==0){
    return res.redirect('/alert.html');
}
else{
    return res.redirect('http://127.0.0.1:8000/acess');
}
```